# iPhone app Preferences Reference

Tags: iphone

Is there a better resource than the following link for programming the preference pane for an iPhone app? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007005

Side question: can the bundle version be automatically picked up from within the Settings.bundle?

Answer (score 1):

The chapter on Application Preferences in the book [Beginning iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224592)

That chapter is excellent (as is the whole book) for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite comprehensive chapter in the iPhone Application Programming guide:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html